# React: Confusing behavior with useEffect and/or useState hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React noob here. I'm trying to make a simple practice app to help with my React learning and I'm getting a lot of odd behavior. It's a Todo app with multiple todo lists to choose from. The behavior I'm going for is a list of Todo lists, where you select one and the todo items for that  (like wunderlist/msft todo). Select a different list and it's todo items show, etc. At this point it's using static json where each item has a child array.

useEffect - I’m trying to use this to load the data. It keeps complaining about missing dependencies. When I add them it complains about that too. It complains if I use and empty array for the second parameter and seems to fire multiple times.

useState - I'm using this to store the data. It's initialized to an empty array. But render is firing before useEffect and it's saying my data is undefined so my second list never renders.

I have several console.logs in the code and they're all firing multiple times.

I'm sure it's just noob mistakes but I'm pretty stumped at this point. Here's my code:

data/Todo.js

```js
const TodoData = [
  {
    Id: 1,
    Title: "Groceries",
    TodoList: [
      {
        Id: 1,
        Title: "Apples"
      },
      {
        Id: 2,
        Title: "Oranges"
      },
      {
        Id: 3,
        Title: "Bananas"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 2,
    Title: "Daily Tasks",
    TodoList: [
      {
        Id: 11,
        Title: "Clean Kitchen"
      },
      {
        Id: 12,
        Title: "Feed Pets"
      },
      {
        Id: 13,
        Title: "Do Stuff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 3,
    Title: "Hardware Store",
    TodoList: []
  },
  {
    Id: 4,
    Title: "Costco",
    TodoList: [
      {
        Id: 21,
        Title: "Diapers"
      },
      {
        Id: 22,
        Title: "Cat Food"
      },
      {
        Id: 23,
        Title: "Apples"
      },
      {
        Id: 24,
        Title: "Bananas"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Id: 5,
    Title: "Work",
    TodoList: [
      {
        Id: 34,
        Title: "TPS Reports"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default TodoData;
```

App.Js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TodoData from "./data/Todo.js";

function App() {
  const [todoData, setTodoData] = useState([]);
  const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (todoData.length === 0) {
      getTodoData();
    }
  }, [todoData]);

  const getTodoData = () => {
    setTodoData(TodoData);
    console.log("getting todo data");
    getTodoDetails(1);
  };

  const getTodoDetails = id => {
    const result = TodoData.filter(x => x.Id === id);
    console.log(result[0]);
    setTodoDetails(result[0]);
  };

  const handleClick = e => {
    const selectedId = Number(e.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
    getTodoDetails(selectedId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="list-group col-md-4 offset-md-1">
            {todoData.map(todos => (
              <button
                key={todos.Id}
                data-id={todos.Id}
                className="btn list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                {todos.Title}
                <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
                  {todos.TodoList.length}
                </span>
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <ul className="list-group">
              <h2>{todoDetails.Title} List</h2>

              {console.log(todoDetails.TodoList)}

              {/* this fails miserably */}
              {/* {todoDetails.TodoList.map(details => (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={details.Id}>
                  {details.Title}
                </li>
              ))} */}

              <li className="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
              <li className="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              <li className="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dan-rdoyh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to the question. If the external link is deleted or modified, the question will have no future value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q :** useEffect - I’m trying to use this to load the data. It keeps complaining about missing dependencies

**A :** you can ignore it via `eslint (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`, there is nothing to worry about

---

**Q :** useState - I'm using this to store the data. It's initialized to an empty array. But render is firing before useEffect and it's saying my data is undefined so my second list never renders.

**A :** Do read the comments in code, hope that will clear your doubts

```
// you are intializing `todoDetails` with array, when there will be object
// hence the error while mapping inside the html/jsx
// const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState([]);

// init with `null`, why?
const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState(null);

// so that you can do something like this
{
  todoDetails && (   // <---------- HERE
    <ul className="list-group">
      <h2>{todoDetails.Title} List</h2>

      {console.log(todoDetails.TodoList)}

      {/* this fails miserably */}
      {todoDetails.TodoList.map(details => (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={details.Id}>
          {details.Title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

---

**Q :** Now you are getting multiple `console.log`,

**A :** the reason behind this is [`<React.StrictMode>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html),

React may invoke render phase lifecycles more than once before committing, or it may invoke them without committing at all (because of an error or a higher priority interruption).

I've removed it from `index.js` in demo, so you can see the diff

---

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit angry-oskar-37rq9]

Answer (score 2):

The code that you commented and said that is failing is due to `todoDetails.TodoList` be undefined on the first time you are rendering the component. To avoid that, either initialize the `todoDetails` with one item or check if `todoDetails.TodoList` is defined before calling the `.map` on it.

```
{todoDetails.TodoList ? todoDetails.TodoList.map(details => (
  <li className="list-group-item" key={details.Id}>
    {details.Title}
  </li>
)) : null}
```

or

```
const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState(TodoData[0]);
```

Don't worry too much about the `eslint (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)` error. You need to understand what this second parameter of the `useEffect` means. In your code, you passed the `todoData` to the `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (todoData.length === 0) {
      getTodoData();
    }
  }, [todoData]);
```

This means that, whenever the `todoData` changes, the `useEffect` will run, behaving like a `componentDidUpdate`. If you pass only an empty array, it means that your useEffect has no dependencies, and it will be executed only once, behaving like a `componentDidMount`. So, what you did is fine here.

Besides that, here are some tips that I can give you about your code:

About your `handleClick` function, you can remove it and simple call the `getTodoDetails(id)` passing the id instead of adding it to the `data-id` and getting it later, this way:

```
<button
  key={todos.Id}
  className="btn list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
  onClick={() => getTodoDetails(todos.Id)} // <---- change is in here
>
  {todos.Title}
  <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
    {todos.TodoList.length}
  </span>
</button>
```

On your `getTodoDetails`, you can change the `filter` to `find`, since you don't need to go through your entire array to find one item, making it more expensive. Plus, with that, you don't need to access the first item of the array.

```
const getTodoDetails = id => {
  const result = TodoData.find(x => x.Id === id);
  console.log(result);
  setTodoDetails(result);
};
```

You are using your `todoDetails` as an `object` and initializing it as an `array`. If your `todoDetails` will always have only one todo, initialize it as an object, this way you can prevent accessing `todoDetails.Title` from an array. The `useEffect` will always be executed after rendering.

```
const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the logic of getTodoData into the `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getTodoData = () => {
      setTodoData(TodoData);
      console.log("getting todo data");
      getTodoDetails(1);
    };

    if (todoData.length === 0) {
      getTodoData();
    }
  }, [todoData.length]);
```

And in rendering

```js
{
  // check todoDetails has TodoList
  todoDetails.TodoList &&
    todoDetails.TodoList.map((details) => (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={details.Id}>
        {details.Title}
      </li>
    ));
}
```

here is the updated [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-bash-wplg7?file=/src/App.js:166-177)

Comment: while ok, note that getTodoData depends on getTodoDetails, so getTodoDetails ought to be moved in as well or specified as deps (in which case useCallback needed)

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook can be weird sometimes. To fix it, you simply pass in your `getTodoData` function directly like so:

```js
 const getTodoData = () => {
  setTodoData(TodoData);
  console.log("getting todo data");
  getTodoDetails(1);
};

useEffect(getTodoData, []);
```

It's important to define the `getTodoData` function before passing it into `useEffect` otherwise you will get an error.

I uncommented your code that "fails miserably" and was able to get everything working flawlessly.

Here is the entirety of your fixed `App.js` file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TodoData from "./data/Todo.js";

function App() {
  const [todoData, setTodoData] = useState([]);
  const [todoDetails, setTodoDetails] = useState([]);

  const getTodoData = () => {
    setTodoData(TodoData);
    console.log("getting todo data");
    getTodoDetails(1);
  };

  useEffect(getTodoData, []);

  const getTodoDetails = id => {
    const result = TodoData.filter(x => x.Id === id);
    console.log(result[0]);
    setTodoDetails(result[0]);
  };

  const handleClick = e => {
    const selectedId = Number(e.target.getAttribute("data-id"));
    getTodoDetails(selectedId);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="list-group col-md-4 offset-md-1">
            {todoData.map(todos => (
              <button
                key={todos.Id}
                data-id={todos.Id}
                className="btn list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                {todos.Title}
                <span className="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
                  {todos.TodoList.length}
                </span>
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <ul className="list-group">
              <h2>{todoDetails.Title} List</h2>

              {console.log(todoDetails.TodoList)}

              {todoDetails.TodoList.map(details => (
                <li className="list-group-item" key={details.Id}>
                  {details.Title}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   );
}
export default App;
```

[This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook) is similar to yours and may help you understand how to avoid errors when using the `useEffect` hook in the future. I hope this helps!